# Enviar datos a otro formulario usando Sweetalert y Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, sweetalert

Quiero enviar dos datos a otro formulario php para que los guarde, pero cuando doy click en el boton, me abre la alerta y doy click en confirmar para enviar los datos, no los enviar. En el codigo ajax las variables 'curp' y 'vacuna', son los datos que quiero enviar al otro php.

Este es mi scrip

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
   
     function aplicarVacuna(){
        Swal.fire({
          title: 'Confirmar',
          text: "¿Esta seguro de aplicar la vacuna?",
          //icon: 'warning',
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
          cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
          confirmButtonText: 'Confirmar',
          cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
          showCloseButton: true

        }).then(function(isConfirm){

          if (isConfirm.value){
          
          $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'guardar_vacuna.php',
           data: 'curp','vacuna',
           datatype: 'php'
          })

        }
        })
      }

    </script>
```

A la hora de dar click en el botón para aplicar la vacuna, no sale la alerta de sweetalert, y al revisar el código en chrome me muestra que tengo un error en el codigo de ajax.

data: 'curp','vacuna', Error en la ultima coma "uncaught syntaxerror: unexpected token ','"

```html
$.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'guardar_vacuna.php',
           data: 'curp','vacuna',
           datatype: 'php',

           success:function(response) {
            console.log(response);
           },
          })
```

Y otro error en el código del botón que envía los datos para guardarlos en el ', el error es 'Uncaught ReferenceError: aplicarVacuna is not defined'

```html
<center><input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="aplicar"         value="Aplicar vacuna" onclick="aplicarVacuna()"></center>
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo no estas comprobando si se realiza o no el envío de datos. En las peticiones por AJAX otro archivo, es importante realizar este tipo de comprobaciones.

El callback "success" es una funcion que se ejecutará una vez que el envío de datos se haya realizado. Entonces, dentro de ella puedes mostrar lo que devolvió en la variable response. 
Además, podes ver que tipo de error hay en la petición ajax desde la consola de Chrome, con F12.

```
$.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'guardar_vacuna.php',
                            data: 'curp','vacuna',
                            datatype: 'php'

 success : function(response) {
        console.log(response); // esto mostrará en la consola de tu navegador la respuesta
    },

})
```

Ten en cuenta que "response" devolverá lo que tu archivo guardar_vacuna.php responda. Es decir, en tu php deberías tener un método que si se ejecuta devuelve "Vacunado", y si no se ejecuta devuelve "No se pudo vacunar", entonces en tu consola verás alguna de esas dos respuestas.

Comment: Ya lo probé y cuando doy click en el botón para que envié los datos, no me muestra la alerta y no envíe los datos

Answer (score 0):

Hay algunos datos que estás omitiendo y tienes algunos errores en la sintaxis. Si nos apoyamos con la versión más reciente de Sweetalert, podemos ver que hay algunos atributos que se encuentran depredados en su 2da versión, te dejo la siguiente liga para que puedas consultar esas modificaciones:

https://sweetalert2.github.io/#methods

A continuación te coloco un ejemplo de como puedes realizar una solicitud POST utilizando AJAX. Para el cuerpo de la solicitud, se están enviando 2 datos (CURP y VACUNA) mismos que pueden ser recuperados en el servidor de destino, en tu caso en el documento **guardar_vacuna.php**.

Como caso práctico en este ejemplo se realiza una solicitud POST al sitio web [httpbin.org](https://httpbin.org) página que nos permite realizar pruebas con solicitudes http.

Este sitio devuelve un JSON con información pertinente a la solicitud realizada, por ejemplo:

[image: Ejemplo del resultado de una solicitud http por el método POST]

Por último, te dejo el ejemplo funcional para que puedas tomarlo, analizarlo y acoplarlo a las necesidades de tu proyecto.

**Javascript**

```js
function aplicarVacuna() {
    Swal.fire({
        title: '¿Esta seguro que desea aplicarse la vacuna?',
        text: 'Para confirmar escriba su CURP:',
        input: 'text',
        icon: 'question',
        inputAttributes: {
            autocapitalize: 'off'
        },
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085D6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#D33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Confirmar',
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
        showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        showCloseButton: true,
        preConfirm: (curp) => {
            const url = 'https://httpbin.org/post';
            let data = {
                CURP: '${curp}',
                VACUNA: 'SARS-CoV-2'
            }
            var request = new Request(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: data,
                headers: new Headers()
            });
            return fetch(request)
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error(response.statusText)
                }
                Swal.fire('Registrado!', 'Se ha registrado la vacuna ' + data.VACUNA + ' con el CURP: ' + curp, 'success');
                console.log(response);
                return response.json()
            })
            .catch(error => {
                Swal.fire('Error', 'Request failed: ${error}', 'error');
            })
        },
        allowOutsideClick: () => !Swal.isLoading()
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
      document.getElementById('txtResultado').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result);

            } else if (
                /* Lea más sobre el manejo de dismissals a continuación */
                result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel
            ) {
                swal.fire('Cancelado', 'El proceso ha sido cancelado :)','warning');
            }
        });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>

<center>
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnAplicar" value="Aplicar Vacuna" onclick="aplicarVacuna()" />

  </br>

  <div id="txtResultado"> </div>
</center>
```

Te comparto la liga en la que me apoyé para realizar el ejemplo:

[sweetalert2.github.io/v10.html#ajax-request](https://sweetalert2.github.io/v10.html#ajax-request)

**PHP (guardar_vacuna.php)**

El servidor responde con un objeto JSON, que es manejado en el `then(response)` de la petición Ajax:

```
<?php

    $arrRespuesta = array(
        "foo" => "valor de bar",
        "bar" => "valor de foo",
    );

    echo json_encode($arrRespuesta);

?>
```